# Java eclipse expression window view the full HttpRequest from @RequestBody

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I am using spring annotation in my java code - with eclipse IDE
in my Controller i have this method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/some/link", produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public AnyDto suggestMapping(@Valid @RequestBody(required = false) SomeDto dto) throws Exception {
   ///some code
return null;
}
```

How could i view the  `Full http request` in eclipse **expression window** (during debug)
when i add  `@RequestBody` to expression window i get an error ?

Answer (score 0):

To view the request, you can add `HttpServletRequest request` to your method signature, e.g.:

```
public AnyDto suggestMapping(@Valid @RequestBody(required = false) SomeDto dto, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
   ///some code
   return null;
}
```

Spring then automatically 'autowires' `HttpServletRequest request` into the method code for you.

`@ResponseBody` is different - it simply takes the return type (`AnyDto`) and will set it as the HTTP response body (i.e. so it's unrelated to the request).